# Hash function for user defined class. How to make friends? :)

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, unordered-map

I have a class C, which has a `string* ps` private data member.
Now, I'd like to have an `unordered_map<C, int>` for which I need a custom hash function.

[According to the c++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash), I can do that like

```
namespace std {
  template<>
  class hash<C> {
  public:
    size_t operator()(const C &c) const
    {
      return std::hash<std::string>()(*c.ps);
    }
  };
}
```

The problem is that I can't seem to make `operator()` and `C` friends so that I could access `ps`.

I have tried this:

```
class C;
template<>
class std::hash<C>;
class C{
  //...
  friend std::hash<C>::operator ()(const C&) const; // error: Incomplete type 
};
// define hash<C> here.
```

but it says that Incomplete type ... in nested name specifier ...

I can't turn around the definitions either, because if class C is defined later, the `hash<C>` has no way to know about `ps`.

What am I doing wrong here? How can this situation be fixed without making `ps` public?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this:

```
class C;
namespace std {
  template<>
  struct hash<C> {
  public:
    size_t operator()(const C &c) const; // don't define yet
  };
}
class C{
  //...
  friend size_t std::hash<C>::operator ()(const C&) const;
};
namespace std {
  template<>
  size_t hash<C>::operator()(const C &c) const {
    return std::hash<std::string>()(*c.ps);
  }
}
```

Or this:

```
class C;
template<>
struct std::hash<C>;
class C{
  friend struct std::hash<C>; // friend the class, not the member function
};
```

(I haven't compiled so there might be a syntax error)

Comment: yes, that's correct, thx, I'll mark it accepted in a sec. In the mean time I also figured out how silly I was! [embarrassed] :)

Comment: for msvc2012, you'll need to remove `template<>` in the implementation of the size_t `hash<C>::operator()`, otherwise `error C2910 cannot be explicitly specialized`.

Comment: +1 for Jichao. On Gcc without removing `template<>`, I get `error: template-id ‘operator()<>’ for ‘std::size_t std::hash<C>::operator()(const C&) const’ does not match any template declaration`

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to make friends:

```
class C {
  template <typename T> friend class std::hash;
};
```

This works even when C is in its own namespace or is a nested class, as std::hash won't have to be forward declared.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest to add method like following

```
class C
{
....
public:  const string* get_ps() const { return ps; }
....
};
```

and use it in the your hash specialization.