# Why do I have to define a hash function for each namespace as the unordered_set?

Tags: c++, boost, hash, namespaces

I wanted to make a hash function for a class I am writing and I wanted to make the hash function a friend of the class so that I didn't have to write an unnecessary getter method. To do that I followed the accepted answer in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890747/hash-function-for-user-defined-class-how-to-make-friends). But I wanted to be able to insert the objects into either `std::unordered_set` or `boost::unordered_set`. So I wrote it like this:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

class Vec;
namespace std { // line [c]
    template<>
    struct hash<Vec> {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Vec &v) const;
    };
}

class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    friend size_t std::hash<Vec>::operator ()(const Vec& v) const; // line [d]
    friend bool operator == (const Vec& lhs, const Vec& rhs) { return lhs.v == rhs.v; }
};

namespace std { // line [e]
    size_t hash<Vec>::operator()(const Vec &v) const {
        return boost::hash<std::vector<int> >()(v.v);
    }
}

int main() {
    Vec v;
    std::unordered_set<Vec> s1; // line [f]
    s1.insert(v); // line [g]
    boost::unordered_set<Vec> s2; // line [a]
    s2.insert(v); // line [b]
}
```

But I found that I had a long list of errors when trying to compile this. Then when I removed lines `[a,b]`, it compiled and ran as expected. Then, instead of removing lines `[a,b]`, I (1) left them in, (2) removed lines `[f,g]`, and (3) changed lines `[c,d,e]` to say `boost` instead of `std`, again the code would compile properly. Finally, I tried making a duplicate declaration of the hash struct in the `boost` namespace:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>

class Vec;
namespace std {
    template<>
    struct hash<Vec> {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Vec &v) const;
    };
}
// new: {
namespace boost {
    template<>
    struct hash<Vec> {
    public:
        size_t operator()(const Vec &v) const;
    };
}
// }

class Vec {
private:
    std::vector<int> v;
public:
    friend size_t std::hash<Vec>::operator ()(const Vec& v) const;
    // new: {
    friend size_t boost::hash<Vec>::operator ()(const Vec& v) const;
    // }
    friend bool operator == (const Vec& lhs, const Vec& rhs) { return lhs.v == rhs.v; }
};

namespace std {
    size_t hash<Vec>::operator()(const Vec &v) const {
        return boost::hash<std::vector<int> >()(v.v);
    }
}
// new: {
namespace boost {
    size_t hash<Vec>::operator()(const Vec &v) const {
        return boost::hash<std::vector<int> >()(v.v);
    }
}
// }

int main() {
    Vec v;
    std::unordered_set<Vec> s1;
    s1.insert(v);
    boost::unordered_set<Vec> s2;
    s2.insert(v);
}
```

My question is: why do I have to make a hash function in both the `std` and `boost` namespace to get it to work? I would say that I have an intuition for why, but I would like a very detailed explanation. And I would like any alternative solutions that would fix the fact that there is a lot of duplicate code in the above code segment (but not something like `boost::unordered_set<Vec, my_vec_class_hash>` because I want it to be "automatic").

Comment: Personally, I would not specialize either `boost::` or `std::` and instead write class called `VecHasher` and then use a `whatever::unordered_set<Vec, VecHasher>`

Comment: You can even use an alias for that like `using unordered_vec_set = whatever::unordered_set<Vec, VecHasher>;`

Comment: Why would there ever be a need to use both boost and std templates for an unordered set? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, I did know that was an option. I just don't know what the standard way to do this is. Your way would eliminate duplicate code, but is it standard practice to provide a separate hashing class for all your classes? I want this to be presentable and look like I know what I'm doing lol.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Admittedly any situation that would require this would be quite contrived.

Comment: I don't know about boost but specializing `std::hash` is explicitly [allowed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.hash#2) by the standard. It's a nice and concise way, there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: In terms of alternative, you could definitely do this through macro. However, I would not recommend this unless you really have a lot of thing that need to be done in similar way.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep no need, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the clutter a long way, by using Boost's ADL-enabled customization point `hash_value`:

```
class Vec {
  private:
    std::vector<int> v;

    friend size_t hash_value(const Vec& v) {
        return boost::hash_range(begin(v.v), end(v.v));
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Vec& lhs, const Vec& rhs) {
        return lhs.v == rhs.v;
    }
};
```

> In fact, the hash function can be even simpler with `return boost::hash_value(v.v);` in this case.

This is already enough to make Boost's unordered containers work with your type:

```
boost::unordered_set<Vec> s2;
s2.insert(v);
```

### Adding std support

That's a non-issue now:

```
template <> struct std::hash<Vec> : boost::hash<Vec> {};
```

### Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4416fa69ff66c09d)**

```
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_set.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

class Vec {
  private:
    std::vector<int> v;

    friend size_t hash_value(const Vec& v) {
        return boost::hash_value(v.v);
        //return boost::hash_range(begin(v.v), end(v.v));
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Vec& lhs, const Vec& rhs) {
        return lhs.v == rhs.v;
    }
};

template <> struct std::hash<Vec> : boost::hash<Vec> {};

int main() {
    Vec v;
    std::unordered_set<Vec> s1;
    s1.insert(v);
    boost::unordered_set<Vec> s2;
    s2.insert(v);
}
```

Comment: Yes that works great! It took me some time to figure out how to separate the class into header and implementation files, then I realized I needed to put the `std::hash<Vec>` initialization in the header.

Comment: Yup. That's called a definition, in particular a definition of a specialization. Maybe you understood this, but in general template definitions need to be visible in all places that may instantiate them, so [need to be in the headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file#:~:text=Templates%20must%20be%20used%20in,given%2Fdeduced%20for%20template%20parameters.&text=When%20you%20compile%20a%20non,compiling%20a%20concrete%20function%2Fclass.)